# Migrate Ember 1.7 to Ember 2.9

Tags: ember.js, migration, ember-cli

We have a quite large app building on top of Ember 1.7. There are quite a significant portion of the code is legacy and we want to refactor/re-architecture to get rid of. The goal is to be on the latest version of Ember (2.9 at this moment), leverage ember engine so later we can port portion of the app to other apps if required. This time is we don't have a lot of request for new features and we have 6-8 weeks to invest in technology updates. Also during this time, we may be required to add some features to the existing app. Our developer(s) may get pulled to work on some other small projects for couple of weeks. We consider being on Ember 2.x is crucial. In 2017, we may not have the time to do the migration. We have 2 options at this moment:

1. Dive with our head down rebuild the app with the latest ember which mean do the refactoring at the same time with migrating. If there are new features, we will add to the old app and migrate later.
2. Refactor first, re-architecture on the 1.7 version of Ember, get rid of the legacy code we don't want and migrate when we're done with refactoring. If we need to add more features to the app, we can add during the refactoring process. When done with refactoring, we will freeze the app from new features.

The first approach is more risky, thing can go out of control because of refactoring and migration at the same time. But if things go well, it could be done in shorter time.

The later approach is much safer. If we run out of time at the end, we still have a better code base. And whenever we have time we can come back to do the migration. But it would takes longer since we will need to do another short of refactor when migrate to ember 2.x. And we may never have time for migration and forever get stuck with Ember 1.7.

We are trying to look for a third approach which is refactoring and migrating a smaller chunks of the app to ember engines or smaller ember apps. And inject these small engines/apps to the existing large legacy app. However, I could not find anywhere which mention we can use Ember 2.x inside an Ember 1.x app.

Any idea, suggestion, tips hint on that we can reach to our goals will be really appreciated. One more thing, the existing app using RequireJS.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think you should think about two migrations:

- migrating to `ember 2.9`,
- and migrating to `ember-cli`

---

The most important question I think is, if it might be possible to jump to `ember 1.13` in a single short step. This highly depends on your usage of private API. If you can jump to `ember 1.13` in a few hours that should be your first step.

If you have a `1.13` app without deprecations, you actually could just jump to `2.x`. So here the number of deprecations will help you to evaluate the required effort.

---

Now lets talk about the jump to `ember-cli`. This will probably be much harder then the jump to `ember 2.9`, because you have to touch every single file! It could be a good idea to do this ASAP, on `1.7` or `1.13`. However if this is a good idea depends on the knowledge of you and your teammates. If you have a decent knowledge of `ember-cli` during the `1.x` phase you could try it. If you don't have that it could be hard to get this knowledge, because this internet is not freezed. And a lot of things have changed since then.

---

If you can get your app on `1.13` with `ember-cli` it's a good point for refactoring and get rid of all the deprecations. Don't over-refactor you code tho. If you can jump to `2.9` do it, and do the refactoring later.

---

If these multi step upgrade is not possible for you, I would recommend your options 1. There are things like [ember-islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands), however I doubt that you will save much time with that.

Probably I would try to rebuild the app on `2.9` with as few refactoring as possible and as much reuse of code as possible. Later start the refactoring to engines.